# How to get the parent directory of a searched folder in Obj-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I was wondering how to get an app name from /var/mobile/Applications (iOS) but the .app folders are within unique directory names.

I was wondering how (or if) I could parse a search on all the folders' child directories for a folder named e.g Messenger.app and return the parent directory (the unique, long folder name it's stored in).

e.g
 The user has 3 apps installed from the App store, One is Facebook.app, another is Twitter.app and the other one is called Messenger.app.
 They are installed to /var/mobile/Applications with unique IDs such as 1183472234-DDFGHSF-33442/AppName.app
 Search for app name Messenger.app within /var/mobile/Applications/* and return the parent directory (e.g 1183472234-DDFGHSF-33442)

Is there any way how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: are you talking about your own app, or other apps?

You can access the "documents directory" for your app, and then see the full path. This is how you can get to the documents directory:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

Now you have your path stored in a NSString called "documentsDirectory". Simply output documentsDirectory to the log or parse it to get the unique directory name. Here is an example output for me:

```
NSLog(@"%@", documentsDirectory);

----

/Users/John/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/CBCEF6C0-3CFE-46EC-BD42-5969104B69D0/Documents
```

I'm using the iOS Simulator, but it will work on real devices as well.